# How to exclude suspended time from elapsed time

Tags: c, linux

I am measuring the runtime of an operation, but my system brings my process in and out of the suspended state during the lifetime of the operation. This is fine, but how can I accurately measure just the running time of my operation.

Comment: Each time your system brings the process in and out of the suspend state you print/get the timestamp, and then you also get the starting timestamp of the process and its ending timestamp. the you do the maths of ending timestamp - starting timestamp - {all occurences of in/out elapsed time}

Comment: See: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/8-ways-to-measure-execution-time-in-c-c-48634458d0f9 and consider `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` with `clock_gettime()` Note that if you're being suspended for reasons that your program causes (e.g. page fault, I/O, etc.) you may want to factor that in. Also, any CPU time consumed by the _kernel_ at the behest of your program. If you do your tests on a quiescent system [which is a good idea], then CPU time and elapsed time (`CLOCK_MONOTONIC`) will track well. Also, look at the `times` linux syscall